# How to determine if webapp has successfully deployed in Hudson or other CI servers?

Tags: maven, deployment

I created a maven deployer module that will deploy select artifacts from the maven repo. This deployer module is configured as a job on Hudson. I want this job to pass if the webapp is successfully deployed, i.e. not only is the servlet container started, but the Spring App Context is successfully loaded. How can I achieve that? Right now the job indicates success even though the Spring App Context has errors but the servlet container says "started".

I thought about creating an integration test that tries to load a Spring bean but it will have to be part of my webapp project, and I don't want to merge the deployment module into my webapp module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to expose a 'health' servlet in your webapp that could (for instance) return 200 if everything's cool (Spring is loaded), or 500 if there's a problem.

You can then have an ant task that uses the ['http' ant condition to pass / fail](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

Comment: Good idea. We do essentially the same on our team, only we use Maven and an integration test (run by maven as part of the build) that uses HTMLUnit to  check that the start page can be loaded and looks right.